# Косметика или косметология?

Tags: употребление-слов

По идее, косметология — это наука, изучающая косметику. Но откуда тогда многочисленные КОСМЕТОЛОГИЧЕСКИЕ кабинеты или рекламные "инновации в области косметологии"? Таким образом, грамотно ли вообще употреблять слово "косметология" в таком контексте?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

КОСМЕТОЛОГИЧЕСКИЕ медицинские кабинеты  проводят  коррекцию врожденных и приобретенных  нарушений покровных тканей человеческого
организма, в том числе возникающих вследствие травм и хирургических вмешательств, химиотерапевтического,лучевого и медикаментозного воздействия
и перенесенных заболеваний; информирование населения о гигиенических рекомендациях по предупреждению заболеваний,  профилактике преждевременного старения и инволюционной деградации кожи и ее придатков,подкожной жировой
клетчатки и мышечного аппарата: удаление татуировки,пирсинг,прокол мочек ушей,криомассаж,пилинг, дермапигментация (перманентный татуаж), пиляция,эпиляция, косметологическая чистка лица и др.ЭТО МЕДИЦИНСКИЕ КОСМЕТОЛОГИЧЕСКИЕ услуги.

Косметические процедуры и мероприятия,применяемые с целью личной гигиены
и коррекции косметических недостатков средствами декоративной косметики,которые касаются поверхностного ухода без нарушения кожного покрова и иных способов
вмешательства в организм-услуги соляриев,косметический массаж,чистка,нанесение масок, макияж,грим - производятся в КОСМЕТИЧЕСКИХ кабинетах.

Comment: Интересно! Я тоже не знала разницы. Спасибо, Людмила!